# Show Keyboard just beneath/under the focused editText

Tags: android

I could able to show the decimal keyboard on android. However, I need to know how could I show the keyboard just under the focused editText or TextView in a popover/fragment?

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Comment: I would make another view as your custom decimal keyboard, then just make it visible when the user selects the edittext, or even an alert dialog popup

Comment: is there any example?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  The keyboard itself is responsible for where it draws.  Which unless they go to a lot of work to override it, is always at the bottom of the screen.  If you absolutely need that, you need to implement a pseudo-keyboard of your own.

Comment: how about floating keyboard?

Comment: All that is controlled by the keyboard app, not by your app.  The keyboard would have needed to program in a floating mode (not all have it), and would need to decide to use that mode for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` set the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute to `adjustResize` for the activity containing your `EditText` as following.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    />
```

Hope this is helpful.